# MRubyでバイナリを日本語に変換するには？

Tags: ruby, mruby

お世話になります。

MRubyでバイナリデータを日本語で出力したいのですが、方法が良く分かりません。

CRubyだと

```
p ['e38193e38293e381abe381a1e381af'].pack('H*').force_encoding('utf-8')
```

=> "こんにちは"

と出力できますが、MRubyだとforce_encodingが無いので

```
p ['e38193e38293e381abe381a1e381af'].pack('H*')
```

=>"\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf"

こうなってしまいます。
MRubyでも"こんにちは"と日本語で出力させるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mrubyは、たしかエンコーディングの仕組みを持ってなかったと思います。
表示用であれば `p` ではなく、`puts` を使うのはいかがでしょうか。

```
% mruby -e 'p "あいうえお"'
"\343\201\202\343\201\204\343\201\206\343\201\210\343\201\212"
% mruby -e 'puts "あいうえお"'
あいうえお
```